# plot dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, plot, group-by

I have a dataframe df below: showing the number of kilometers done per day per type of people by type of car.

```
People      Car         dmy         value(km)
A         Renault    14-05-2016     500
B         Peugeot    14-05-2016     1000
A         Citroen    14-05-2016     400
A         Renault    15-05-2016     24
B         Peugeot    15-05-2016     247
A         Renault    15-05-2016     369
A         Citroen    23-05-2016     692
A         Citroen    28-05-2016     284
```

I have 20k lines over 1 year

I want to group by the dmy column to get the mean value of the 'value(km)' column per day

This is what I have done:

I first create a new dataframe given 2 conditions: My graph will only show the mean value of kms per day for 1 type of car and 1 category of people.

```
 yy = (df["Car"] == 'Renault') & (df["People"] == 'A')
```

Then I create a dataframe to perform the group.by

```
zz = yy.groupby('dmy')['value(km)'].mean()
```

And set the dmy column as the index

zz = zz.set_index('dmy')

Then I plot this new zz dataframe:

```
plt.plot(zz.index, zz["value"].values, linestyle='-', color='b', label="Renault")
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

No plots appear though. Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupby` returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` and not a  `Dataframe`.

I would first select the necessary columns and then call `aggregate` and eventually `plot`:

```
import numpy as np
zz = yy[['value(km)', 'dmy']].groupby('dmy').aggregate(np.mean)
zz.plot()
```